# PHPEXCEL Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted Issue for addTableRow() method

Tags: cakephp-1.3, phpexcel, php-5.3

First of all I know there is huge memory usage for PHPExcel while creating Excel sheet from database. I am using mysql database and the rows returned are about 14K plus. I need to generate Excel sheet for these records.

It is possible to generate Excel sheet using this code for small entries, however for 14K records this code is breaking. I saw caching cell techniques but being a newbie with PHPExcel I find it very difficult.

Can anyone guide me to solve this issue.

Source: https://github.com/segy/PhpExcel

Below is my code snippet:

```
App::import('Component', 'PhpExcel');
$phpExcelObj = new PhpExcelComponent();
$phpExcelObj->createWorksheet()->setDefaultFont('Calibri', 12);
// define table cells
$table = array(
array('label' => ('Id'), 'wrap' => true),
array('label' => ('Name'), 'wrap' => true, 'filter' => true),
array('label' => ('Email_id'), 'wrap' => true, 'filter' => true),
array('label' => ('status'), 'wrap' => true, 'filter' => true)
            );
$phpExcelObj->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'Cambria', 'bold' => true));
$indx = 1;
foreach ($ckt_dtls as $usr_dtls) {
$rows[] = $indx;
$rows[] = $usr_dtls['name'];
$rows[] = $u_email;
$rows[] = $stat;
$indx++;
$phpExcelObj->addTableRow($rows);
}
$phpExcelObj->addTableFooter()->output($filename = $filename, $writer = 'Excel2007');
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 57 bytes) in /var/www/4thambit_v6/app/vendors/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php on line 1218
```

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the memory limit PHP is using for your script, putting the following code in the beginning: `ini_set("memory_limit", "2048M");`
If it doesn't work, try with a number bigger than `2048M`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to worry about memory or can't change the `memory_limit` setting, you can try using [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) instead.

I am not aware of any CakePHP wrapper around this library, but it should not be too hard to use it in your project. Just follow the instructions here: https://github.com/box/spout#manual-installation

Writing 14K should take a few seconds and not more than 10MB of memory!